# Windows Phone - Extend existing Style with Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a Style defined in my App.xaml file:

```
    <Style x:Key="TileListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,12,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="210"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="210"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now I need to change the Background property with a Binding within my PhoneApplicationPage XAML file:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TileListBoxItemStyle2" TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TileListBoxItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The following Exception is thrown:

```
{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Failed to assign to property         'System.Windows.Setter.Value'. [Line: 23 Position: 49] ---> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot set read-only property ''.
       at MS.Internal.XamlMemberInfo.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
       at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.SetValue(XamlTypeToken inType, XamlQualifiedObject& inObj, XamlPropertyToken inProperty, XamlQualifiedObject& inValue)
```

This does not work although I searched the web and it seems to work, but maybe there's a limitation of Windows Phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to have a binding in a Style setter in windows phone but maybe this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/10/the-taming-of-the-phone-new-settervaluebindinghelper-sample-demonstrates-its-usefulness-on-windows-phone-7-and-silverlight-4.aspx) can help you.
Otherwise the only thing I see you can do is create a class inheriting ListBox, orveride GetContainerForItemOverride and create the binding in code.